# Putting Json objects in fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fancybox

When the user clicked the first row then the view button, I would like to use Fancybox to view the information of A. The table below is in fancybox already.

```
| Id | Name |
|  1 |  A   |
|  2 |  B   |
```

I used ajax to get the information and I'm getting the correct information. However I don't know how to place these information in the fancybox. How can this be implemented? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
$("#viewUser").click(function() {
    var string = $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: 'home/viewUser', 
                     async: false,
                     data: {'id': id}, 
                     dataType: "JSON"
               }).responseText;
    var temp=JSON.parse(string);
    var firstName = temp.firstName;
    var lastName = temp.lastName;
    var username = temp.username;
    var email = temp.email;
    var userType = temp.userType;
    var area = temp.area;

    $.fancybox({ 
        'width': '50%', 
        'height': '62%', 
        'autoScale': true,
        'autoSize': false,  
        'transitionIn': 'fade', 
        'transitionOut': 'fade', 
        'type': 'inline', 
        'href': '#viewUser_fancybox',
        'modal': true

    }); 
    return false;

     });
})
```

Comment: try using ajax `success` to render the response in fancybox as in http://fancybox.net/blog == No.5. Bear in mind that you can have only ONE fancybox opened at a time. Calling a fancybox from within fancybox will close the first one and open the second (no need to close manually the first though)

Comment: Hi again! I tried your suggestion and I could open another fancybox now. But how do I access the json objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can open fancybox with ajax content.
My suggestion is returning html content when you make a call to **"home/viewUser?id=your_id"** and implement fancy box like;

```
<a class="user-info fancybox.ajax" href="home/viewUser?id=your_id">User Info</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user-info").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Comment: The first table is in fancybox and I want to open another fancybox. Would this solution still work in codeigniter?

Comment: Fancybox is a single instance script. If you try to open fancybox from another fancybox, first fancybox will be closed and another will be open. I have prepared a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/5EV8r/156/

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks! I have another question. When using an inline type of fancybox, is there a way to pass a variable using the href? For example, 'href':'#viewUser_fancybox?email='+email+''

Comment: If you are using inline, you cannot do that operation. What kind of result do you expect when you use viewUser_fancybox?email='+email? You are using inline div, so url param like structure doesn't work

Comment: I was hoping that I could just use $_GET('email') but like you said, it won't work. I tried your way but it now redirects to another page. I'll update my question above.

Comment: If page redirects, you need to put absolute url href="home/viewUser?id=your_id"